# Load desired EJBs only

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, java-ee-7

Technology I'm using: JavaEE7, JSF2.2.

I have one project called "entity" which contains all the entity, repository, DAO (Stateless EJB).

Other projects will import "entity" project and use this project to connect to DB.
The problem is that "entity" project contains over 5000 EJB, and this takes a lot of time for loading.

But in reality, each project only uses hundreds of EJB.

Can I have a way to load only EJBs that I will really use, without loading all 5000 EJBs. For example: define needed EJBs in .xml file

Answer (score 0):

Split the "entity" project in reasonable parts.